# how to test if a new file is added to a directory and do something

Tags: batch-file

I need to check if a new PDF file is added in a directory and then I do something.

for that I start with this batch script:

```
@echo off

:loop
  IF exist "*.pdf" (for %%i in (*.pdf) do set pdfname_new=%%i) ELSE ( goto loop)
  ECHO %pdfname_new%
goto loop
```

When I create the first PDF file test1.pdf it works fine and it prints test1
then when I added test2.pdf it works also and it prints test2.

the problem when I add test0.pdf it prints test2

I noticed that it doesn't process the last pdf file created but it must be the last in alphabetical order also.

how can I process the last file created even though it is not sorted the last in alphabetical order ??

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /o:d *.pdf') do set "file=%%~i">nul 2>&1` The last modified file should be the last sorted file, and will be the file we've set in the variable `%file%` therefore `echo "%file%" after that line should carry the latest file..

Comment: To clarify, it never prints `test2`, because `%pdfname_new%` would always resolve to `test2.pdf`, _(`set pdfname_new=%%~ni` would do what you've actually posted as the output.)_. The problem is that your output is not ordered as you'd like it. To resolve that you need to ensure that your command iterates the files ordered as you need. Because you've said new files, Gerhard has assumed that the date order would arrange your files more appropriately for your needs, and has provided a solution for that. If you want the dates ordered other than by `modified`, use the `/T` option with `C` or `A`.

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing a batch file is not designed for an event triggered task. Your loop as currently written takes 100% of one core of the processor just for checking if a PDF file is created in or copied to a directory. So this solution is a very bad solution. There should be at least added command `timeout` to wait a few seconds before running the next file check which frees the core power for other tasks. It would be best to work with the archive attribute as the archive attribute is always set automatically on a file created or modified in a directory.

Comment: Example for a better code: First line `@echo off`, second line `:Loop`, third line `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*.pdf" /AA-D /B 2^>nul') do %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -a "%~dp0%%I" & echo Processing file "%~dp0%%I"`, fourth line `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C EN /N /D N /T 5 /M "Exit batch file with key E ..."`,  fifth and last line `if errorlevel 2 goto Loop`. Command __DIR__ outputs only files with archive attribute set. The archive attribute is first removed on a file before being further processed which is in this example just printing the file name.

Comment: The last line uses command `choice` to wait for user pressing key `E` in which case the batch file processing is exited. Otherwise option `N` is taken after a time of five seconds resulting in running the __FOR__ command once again. The command __CHOICE__ does not take CPU power on waiting for a key press by the user. So the core usage is minimal for this example batch file.

Comment: What about resetting the Archive attribute of already processed PDF files and just processing those found by `dir /A:-DA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the last modified date by using `dir /o:-d` (last modified file will be last in list)

```
@echo off
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /o:d "*.pdf"') do set "file=%%~i">nul 2>&1
echo "%file%"
timeout 5 /Nobreak >nul
goto :loop
```

or if you want to purely focus on the creation date/time of the file using `/t:c` also specified by Compo in a comment.

```
@echo off
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /o:d /t:c "*.pdf"') do set "file=%%~i"
echo "%file%"
timeout 5 /Nobreak >nul
goto :loop
```